# iOS mime-extension

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

So, I am working on an iOS app using phonegap. Apparently my app in iOS has to be running the background for it to open with an email attachment properly. And my app only does something when that email attachment is click on.

But if I don't have the app process in the background it does nothing. Just opens my app as if it didn't read the attachment. This happens in the real device.

In the simulator if I open the attachment without the process in the background it stops at:
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
and gives me the following message:
Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGKILL"
Then when I hit continue, it goes on and opens the attachment properly.

Also, this thing does not happen in the android device.